# How to subcribe/follow a user with spring boot

Tags: spring

I have two entities BlogPost and user im not sure how the follow mechanism works I have searched on S.O but could not get an idea

**What I think**

I think follow is some sort of `Get posts where userID = ?`
but also it should be a continues process ie when user posts again it should automatically get the new post, until user unfollows.

I would like some suggestions on how to go about implementing and what i will need.

What i am trying to create
I want to create a service that subcribes to a user (like in the social networks such linkedIn, so a user can follow another user there by getting all the users new activities such as new posts (new uploads)

```
public void subscribeToUser(String id){
    //follow a user by id 
    //im not sure the relationship i should create between the entities 
    // user and posts so that when one user creates a post 
    // another user can subscribe to the first user and can see all the posts and future posts of the user
}
```

}

Comment: You really, really need to clarify your question, and give some context. What are you trying to create? How should it work? What did you try? What is the concrete question?

Comment: @JBNizet i have added some more description , i have entities but i dont know how to go about writing the service

Comment: If "a user can follow another user", then the association is between a user and a user. Not between a post and a user.